# Save form data in Django on each http request

Tags: django

I’m new to web programming and Python. I’m having a Django app with multiple questions, each of which has a form (a text field) placed on a separate page. On top there’s a ribbon with buttons - one for every single question, as well as “save and go to next question” button.
The problem: form data is lost when other than “save and go next” button is used. I don’t want to lose form data, I want to save on each page change.

What I did: I’m about to finish my prototype where I did a small url scheme change:
Before: UID/question_ID_to_be_opened
After: UID/question_ID_to_be_opened/previous_question_ID
The modified view function shall handle the save of “previous_question_ID”, but this don’t look quite elegant.

Shall I use signals, or redirects, or something else? There is an autosave script too, it is based on a timer - perhaps I can trigger it manually?

Best regards,

Ivan

Comment: I would suggest you post every time a button is clicked and work with success_url of the view to redirect the user to the next question.
If you can provide some code samples of the views it would be easier to give specific suggestions.

Comment: exactly like Armin suggested, use AJAX calls with POST method to save data and go to the next form